# Scrapy requires installing Pillow 4.0.0 or later

Tags: scrapy

I wrote a spider and I ran it on my windows PC. Everything was working fine. I wanted to switch now to my Raspberry Pi and I get the error:

```
"2022-08-06 14:23:16 [scrapy.middleware] WARNING: Disabled CustomImagePipelines: ImagesPipeline requires installing Pillow 4.0.0 or later
2022-08-06 14:23:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]"
```

although I installed Pillow and image.

Has anyone an idea, what could be the problem? Is there any other hidden package, that needs to be installed that I missed? On myRaspberry I should have installed Pillow 9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the issue.
I had a look into the source code and it tries to import
"from PIL import Image". And this gave some error due to missing libraries.

I installed them, now everything is working fine.